# Python script to scrape excel data?

Tags: python, excel, scripting, xlrd

I'm learning python, but I'm stuck on a personal challenge where I try to write a script that scrapes excel data in a specific way.

In column A, each cell has the value foo1, foo2, foo3...

In row 1, each cell has the value bar1, bar2, bar3... 
(0,0) is excluded.

Each row gets at least one 'x' in one of the cells. For example, there might be an 'x' in row foo14, column bar11 (eg the value of x in (15, L)

I want to search for the Xs, grab the associated foo and bar values, then write them to a CSV output file.

I've learned to load Excel docs, grab data from fields, count fields, etc. I can write that data to CSV files. But as for the rest of this challenge, I'm not quite sure where to even start.

Comment: Retrieve/extract what's the **real/core** problem before asking, please.

Comment: There are several similar questions about how to select data in a dataframe row based on a value in a row. E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796085/finding-elements-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Found a solution, thanks